# How do I make a rope/chain(and attach it to a player) in Godot 3

Tags: godot

I am making a platform-like game in Godot where the player is attached to a cord at all times. I have no idea how to go along attaching the player to a rope. at the moment I have a player who is a kinematicbody2d and when he is attached to the cord (which I made out of a line of pin joints) with a pinjoint2d the cord does not hold/puul on the player and instead starts glitching intensively. would making the player a rigidbody2d instead solve the problem? if it does where can I find a good tutorial on how to make a rigidbody2d character? if it doesn't how do I make it work for kinematicbody2d? thanks in advance.
I found this project that is basically what I want
https://godotforums.org/discussion/25597/rope-game-prototyping
but there is no tutorial and I don't understand how the source code works.

Answer (score 1):

For the chain to be able to pull on the characters, the characters must be rigid bodies.

You need to understand, at least at a superficial level, how the physics engine works. It moves objects, checks if they violated any constraint (this includes colliding), and then course corrects.

So, when a rigid body moves "pulling the chain", it is just moving. Then the engine notices that the constraint (the joint in this case) is violated, and corrects for that by pulling the first chain link. Then the first chain link moves, the next joint is being violated, and so on.

This is what everybody would intuitively do: the rigid body has a large mass and the links have a small mass. That results in a large mass ratio between them. And if the mass ratio between them is large, a small motion of the rigid body will result in a strong force on the link. And the link goes flying away, then that throws away the next link, and so on. Result: the links are glitching all over the place. Solution: Give them similar mass (it is also probably a good idea to not give friction to the chain).

See also:

- [Designing with Physics: Bend the Physics Engine to Your Will](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwPIoVW65pE)

---

As per making a rigid body based character. You are going to use forces and impulses.

There is an official demo project: [physics platformer](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/tree/master/2d/physics_platformer).

And here a few video tutorials:

- [Godot 3.0: Rigid Bodies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsAyx2r1bQU)
- [Platform movement in Godot: RigidBody2D vs KinematicBody2D tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnBioV2HkS8)
- [How to Apply Forces to a RigidBody in Godot (2D & 3D)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSFkAzXQSWE)